# White, Black Screen on Supend

Tags: 20.04, suspend

When I suspend my laptop white, black screen appeared
processor: AMD pro a8-8600 b r6 computer cores 4c + 6g * 4 graphics : AMD Radeon r6 graphics.

Comment: Hello. If you are really using 12.04 it went EOL many years ago and is not supported on this site. April 28, 2017

Comment: hey, No i am using 20.04

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 12.04 ESM was in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/03/15/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-reaches-end-of-life-on-april-28-2017/ *Your question states you're using 12.04, so if using 20.04 correct your question. Comments are for us to ask you questions, you reply via edits to question*

Comment: Hey you need to remove the 12.04 tag update the question and use the correct tag.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know